# Can citrix remote admin track my clipboard usage on home computer

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard, citrix-receiver

I use my work computer through remote connection when I am home. I noticed that whenever I copy something on the remote connection it shows up in the clipdiary on home computer. Can the citrix admin monitor that stuff got copied to home computer. If that is the case then they probably can know what else I am copying and pasting on my home machine also i.e my private activities ?

Answer (score 1):

The admin would have to be shadowing your session continually and pasting whenever they suspect you've copied something, or have written custom software to continually dump everything in the clipboard to a file. I've never seen anything like that installed, but it's possible. You can edit the ICA file to disable clipboard sharing if you suspect something wrong.